# Jenkins Gearman plugin configuration groovy

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, automation, gearman

I'm trying to configure Jenkins Gearman plugin using groovy, but can't add the configuration, just get info about existing configuration.

```
import hudson.plugins.gearman.GearmanPluginConfig
import jenkins.model.GlobalConfiguration

GearmanPluginConfig conf = GlobalConfiguration.all().get(GearmanPluginConfig.class)
conf.getHost()
conf.getPort()
```

I'm getting info about host and port, how can I set this properties?

Classes which i'm using located here: https://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack-infra/gearman-plugin/tree/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/gearman/GearmanPluginConfig.java

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the searching found solution here: https://github.com/amihura/jenkins-groovy-scripts